# SQLSTATE[22018] error in PDO prepare statement

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am just using MS Access Database. I am trying to show the data of employee in the last of a year from MS Access Database using PDO prepare statement in PHP.

This is the code:

index.php

```
<?php

    require_once "config.php";
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");

    echo "<h3>Employee Data</h3><br><br>";
    
    // START PDO SELECT
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT USERINFO.Name, USERINFO.Gender, CHECKINOUT.*, IIf(CHECKINOUT.Update = '', '[[ empty ]]', CHECKINOUT.Update) AS update_costum FROM CHECKINOUT 
                LEFT JOIN USERINFO  ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID
                WHERE CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN ? AND ?";
        
        $dateFrom1 = "(Date()-360)";
        $dateTo1 = "Date()";
        //$dateFrom2 = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
        //$dateTo2 =  date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime("-1 years"));
        
        $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $dateFrom1 );
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $dateTo1 );
        $stmt->execute(); // return -1 ?
        echo $stmt->rowCount() . "<br><br>";
        while ($ds_emp = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "User ID: " . $ds_emp["USERID"] . " || ";
            echo "Nama : " . $ds_emp["Name"] . " " . $ds_emp["Gender"] . " || ";
            echo "CHECKTIME : " . $ds_emp["CHECKTIME"] . " || ";
            echo "Update : " . $ds_emp["update_costum"];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

After run the code, I get a couple of weird things.

1. The `$stmt->rowCount();` return -1.
2. The `$ds_emp` only have a few data, not as expected. If I run the query directly in MS Access, the query return all of the data like what I expected.
3. The last line in the page show me this error.

```
SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (SQLFetchScroll[-3030] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:543)
```

Did I put wrong parameters or the query?
I think my query syntax is not wrong.

Why does `$stmt->rowCount();` return -1?

Why are only few data stored in $ds_data variable?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `$link` declaration variable is not shown here but to avoid this error it should be like this one

```
$dbName = "C:\\path\\to\\db.mdb";
$link = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```